# How to schedule service in Apache Felix?

Tags: osgi, scheduler, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, declarative-services

I have deployed some Declarative Services OSGI in my bundle. After my bundle is started, these Services are activated and do some code in run() of Thread. However, I would like to schedule the time to start the run().

```
@Component(name = "ABC"
          ,immediate = true
          ,enabled = true)
public class test {

    private volatile boolean isStarted;

    @Activate
    public void activate() {
        System.out.println("activate");
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runIt();
            }
        };
        t.setDaemon(true);
        isStarted = true;
        t.start();
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void deactivate() {
        System.out.println("DEactivate");
        isStarted = false;
    }

    private void runIt() {
        while (isStarted) {
            System.out.println("OK");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some annotations to your class

```
@Component(name="ABC", service = Runnable.class, immediate = true,
    property = {
            Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=COOL",
            "scheduler.concurrent:Boolean=false",
            "author.check:Boolean=false",
            "scheduler.expression=0 * * * * ?",
            "scheduler.runOn=SINGLE"
    })
```

you can see all available options here https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-commons-scheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.java